# Unity C#- OnTriggerEnter is called but character controller object is passing through

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player object that has a character controller attached and moves with keyboard inputs.

I also have a door object that I want to open on collision triggers with the character, and if the door object needs key, I want it to open only when the character has key.

The door has rigidbody, collider, and `isTrigger` is on. Somehow though, `OnTriggerEnter` is called, but player passes through the door, and if the player has key or if `needKey` is false, the player doesn't pass through. I've tried `OnTriggerstay` and it's the same.

This is the door script

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

        GameObject key = null;
        if(other.gameObject.tag=="Player"){

            if(needKey){

                Debug.Log ("checking!"); //prints fine
                if(troll.gameObject.activeSelf && tc.carryingKey){
                    key = troll.transform.FindChild("key_" + this.gameObject.name).gameObject;

                }

                if(key!=null){
                    Debug.Log(key.name);
                    StartCoroutine(OpenTheDoor());
                    tc.Skill();
                    needKey=false;
                    Destroy(key);
                    key=null;
                }else{
                    //Debug.Log("no key"); //prints fine
                }
            }else{
                StartCoroutine(OpenTheDoor());
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help or idea would be great!

Comment: Triggers don't block movement. Are you expecting them to, or is there some detail I'm missing?

Comment: It's a pretty straight-forward misunderstanding but raises another good point - how would you have a collider that does block movement, while also firing a trigger function? Would you use two colliders?

Answer (score 7):

Trigger doesn't block movement. You should uncheck the isTrigger box. Then if you want to check collision to open the door or blocking player, use OnCollisionEnter instead of OnTriggerEnter.